# How can I fix the gap at the top of my new struts?

Tags: suspension, buick, struts, lacrosse

There is a gap between the body of the car and the bottom of the plate that attached to the top of the struts.

I see it on both sides, but here are pictures from the driver's side:
[image: With weight on the wheels]

When the front end is the car is jacked up there is no gap:
[image: jacked up]

I am confident I got them in the proper side. I had a couple different websites say this was the right part for the car.

2014 Buick Lacrosse

MONROE quick struts

- Front right 272528
- Front left 272529